# Adsense ads close with "navigation canceled" error in Internet Explorer

Tags: google-adsense, internet-explorer

Many years ago I set up Doubleclick for Small Business, showing a mix of custom banners and Adsense.

Recently I installed Windows 8, and I am starting to use Internet Explorer again.

What I noticed is that I get this behaviour on ad banners:

1. If the banner is a custom banner, it's shown
2. If the banner is an adsense, is shown for a split-second, then replaced by an IE error page saying "Navigation canceled"

How is that possible?

What I can do? I Googled but I didn't found a solution.

Comment: I disabled the DNT option and rebooted, the problem is still there

Comment: sounds like a browser issue and not a webmaster issue, tried Microsoft's Internet Explorer Support Site? http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie

Comment: Well, I don't care if on my browser ads aren't shown. I care if it's not shown on other users browsers. I can't put a notice "please do this regedit fix, so I can show ads to you"

Comment: Well there's nothing you can do since its a 'browser issue' Windows 8 has numourus reports of flash not displaying as it was disabled by default, now its enabled people still report issues with adverts as you know.... There's nothing you can do until they release a fix unless people do manual fixes.. So either wait, or disable flash based adds in favor of text ads.

Comment: It also happens in XP on IE>8, so that's why it's strange. Also now flash is enabled by default on MetroIE

Comment: Well as you know millions use XP IE8 and I've never heard of problems with advertising blocked and I imagine if this is the case for you then maybe something on your end is blocking it, or the website is doing something it shouldn't.  I have Windows XP IE8 and Windows 8 here: Care to share the URL so I can see?

Comment: Well, I was wondering because I got the problem on ALL my websites - anyway it looks like it's because of an Artisteer javascript bug, I'm investigating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by a javascript in my webpage, which was refreshing the page to apply transparency on IE. (Artisteer 4.1 skin)

I updated my ad tags to use the new asynchronous loading, and now ads are shown on IE